# Limit embedded DB memory usage & write to file immediately

Tags: spring-boot, h2, hsqldb

I want to have a file based SQL Database for my Spring Boot application that does not need a dedicated database server and works out of the box, something like HSQLDB or H2.
Additionally I want that database to primarily work on the file system and limit its memory usage. Yet whether I use HSQLDB or H2, changes are only saved to disk on shutdown and memory usage explodes.

I'd like to immediately save all changes to my database to disk and not keep all of it in memory all the time.
My Spring Boot datasource url is currently: `jdbc:hsqldb:file:data/xxx`.

Am I misunderstanding the capabilities of HSQLDB and H2 or am I missing a configuration setting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is configurable

```
jdbc:hsqldb:file:filename;hsql.default_table_type=cached;hsqldb.cache_size=500;hsqldb.write_delay=false
```

The settings indicate disk based tables, with 500KB used for memory cache (the actual memory usage is perhaps twice the amount) and immediate writing of changes to disk.

Comment: I had already tried out those settings. This time I looked harder and found my problem: Neither Windows Explorers default directory view, nor the file search tool "Everything" show/update the dynamically changing file size of the HSQLDB files: You have to right click on the files and click properties to see its current size! The drives properties refreshes the proper used/free space by clicking on the window. I guess it's because the files are kept open by HSQLDB. On closing my application the file size would refresh, that's why I thought it didn't work during runtime.